# include owl api jar files into an executable jar file

Tags: java, executable-jar, owl-api

I am developing a java application that uses the owl api (v 5.1.19). Everything works fine when I run the app from eclipse.

I need to extract the app as an executable jar file. But when I do so and run the jar file, the owl api throws the following exception.
Note that all the dependencies needed by the owl api are extracted in the jar file.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.of(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindSink$OfRef.get(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindSink$OfRef.get(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findAny(Unknown Source)
       at org.semanticweb.owlapi.utilities.Injector.getImplementation(Injector.java:246)
        at org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager(OWLManager.java:119)
        at utils.OntologyUtils.loadOntology(OntologyUtils.java:251)
        at persistence.OntologyDAO.loadWholeOntology(OntologyDAO.java:31)
        at application.OntologyHandler.<init>(OntologyHandler.java:21)
        at application.RecommendationAlgorithm.<init>(RecommendationAlgorithm.java:42)
        at ui.MainPage.<init>(MainPage.java:37)
        at ui.TestUI.main(TestUI.java:9)
```

Comment: Looks like the fat jar classloading is having difficulties. My guess would be that you omitted some necessary item(s) when creating it

Comment: Please share how you're combining the jars. The error is related to missing resources that are part of the OWLAPI jar files (not their dependencies). Similarly, there are resource files with the same names but different content in different OWLAPI jars, so merging them requires the tool to be aware.

Comment: I extract the project from eclipse as a runnable jar file and choose to "package the required libraries into jar" option

Comment: If this isn't working, I'd be inclined to make it into a Maven project (assuming it isn't already - please say if I'm wrong) and then you have various options to make at *somewhat* less proprietary way of making fat jars

Comment: It's not a maven project actually. I will give it a try.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: OK. I use Maven Shade personally